# Magento 2 Localization Adding Links in CSV

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3, csv, localisation, translate

How to add text with link in csv file of a module. For example,

```
"An error occurred"
```

I want to add text with link like below for this message.

```
"An error occurred.Please contact our customer service<a href="http://some-link">here</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Following Way..

**i have converted  French langugae**

```
"An error occurred.Please contact our customer service<a href=""%1"">here</a>","Une erreur est survenue.Veuillez contacter notre service clientèle<a href=""%1"">ici/a>"
```

**and direct link add below way...**

```
See PayPal Feature Support details and list of supported regions<a href=""https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/"" target=""_blank"">here</a>.","Voir les détails PayPal des fonctionnalité de support et de la liste des régions prises en charge <a href=""https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/"" target=""_blank"">ici</a>."
```

Comment: I believe %1 parameter is coming from the code. Is there a way to to include the link directly in csv?

Comment: yes i have used and working for me  @blakcaps

Comment: Could you share an example for that?

Comment: yes sure check it  http://prntscr.com/o7roq1 @blakcaps

Comment: Just checking <a href=""http://www.yahoo.com"">here</a> Will this work if added directly like this in csv?

Comment: not working for me.

Comment: add link zip code working messege form checkout page